# setText of a TextView array

Tags: java, android

What I'm trying to do is have an EditText where people enter their names. As people press the "Add Player" button, the name which they just typed appears below in the list form. So I've created 8 textviews which are initially invisible but as people type the name press the "Add Player" button, the text changes to their names and becomes visible.

So I set up a TextView array of the list of names, which are all text views

```
TextView[] nameList = new TextView[]{name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8};
```

Later on in the code in the onClick section, I had

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    String name = etName.getText().toString();
    nameList[i].setText(name);
    nameList[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

However, with this, whenever I press the "add player" button, the app crashes and I get a NullPointerException. How would I solve this?

The problem isn't with the for loop as the app crashed without it. The problem seems to be with the array as if I put

```
name1.setText(name);
name1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

the code worked fine.

Comment: check etName isn't null.
check nameX textView isn't null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your haven't properly initialized your array, since `nameList[i]` is null. Try:

```
nameList[0] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
nameList[1] = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
// etc
```

Comment: This stopped the app crashing but it changes all 8 TextViews to the String name.

Comment: I would guess that's because you are asking for the same string with `String name = etName.getText().toString();`... You need to change `etName` to reference the appropriate EditText.

Comment: the thing is, I'm trying to have one EditText but as each time the user presses "Add Player" button, the names appear below.

Comment: Ok, then you shouldn't use a loop in your `onClick()` method. Make `i` a field variable and only use `i++`. This way each time you click "Add Player" it will reveal one new TextView with the current name. (You should also make sure the user doesn't try to add a 9th player, otherwise you'll see the NPE again.)

Answer (score 0):

Without further info as to where you're setting etName (which is almost certainly your problem) it's hard to know where you're getting your null (your stack trace will give you a line number which should tell you that, btw) but aside from that you should not put an array of fields together as you are doing and then setting the number 8 as a hard coded number in your activity.  Rather, you should first loop through your activity and construct that array based on how many Views you have that are named nameX (where X is a number that goes from 0 upwards as many times as you want).  That way you will always have the exact right number of iterations.

If you don't know how to look for `Views` based on their XML id, chime in and I will add the code for that.